# Creating multiple objects with same variables

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out how to create several objects from the main object

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
var player = {
    var totalScore = 0;
    var playing = true;
    function checkScore() {
       if (totalScore >= 100) {
            playing = false;
       }
    };
};

player playerAI = new player();
player playerOne = new player();
```

Comment: Objects aren't function.

Comment: I've edited the code to make it easier to read

Comment: player is already an object. its not a template for creating new objects. in javascript functions play the role of being a template through which you can create new objects.

Comment: http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html

Comment: I'm thinking of it as a class from java(no reference), this is why objects confuse me so much. So if i want to have few objects with same variables but different values, i have to simply write two separate objects?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, javascript is very confusing!

Comment: No, it's not confusing. Like any other programming language, or anything in life for that matter, you need to know and follow the rules. For instance, we create a new object using the `new` operator on a **function**. A function is declared using the `function` keyword, as in `function player() { }`. Within the function, we can set object properties by saying things like `this.totalScore = 0;`. This is not confusing, it's basic, and it's covered in any basic JS tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've re-written your code as a *Constructor* in *JavaScript*

```
function Player() {
    this.totalScore = 0; // `this` will refer to the instance
    this.playing = true;
}
Player.prototype.checkScore = function () { // the prototype is for shared methods
    if (this.totalScore >= 100) {           // that every instance will inherit
        this.playing = false;
    }
};

var playerAI = new Player(),
    playerOne  = new Player();
```

Some of your code patterns don't look like *JavaScript* though, are you sure you're not using a different language? (such as Java)

Comment: Yeah i'm thinking of java when i write code but then i keep reminding myself its javascript, hard to find mistakes now since eclipse luna doesn't validate javascript :(

Comment: @Evald Well, go out and find yourself one of the dozens of competent JavaScript IDEs if you actually are serious about programming in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var player = function() {
    this.totalScore = 0;
    this.checkScore = function() {
        if (totalScore >= 100) {
        playing = false;
    }    
};
player playerAI = new player();
player playerOne = new player();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define a constructor function
var Player = function () {

    // This acts as public property
    this.playing = true;

    // This acts as public method
    this.isPlaying = function (){
        return this.playing;
    };
};
```

Usage:

```
var player1 = new Player();
console.log(player1.isPlaying());
```

Note: It's better to declare your methods as properties of the `Player.prototype` object. (For memory saving)

```
Player.protoype.isPlaying = function (){
    return this.playing;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
function player() {
    var totalScore = 0;
    var playing = true;
    return {
        checkScore: function checkScore() {
            if (totalScore >= 100) {
                playing = false;
            }
        }
    }
};

var playerAI = new player();
var playerOne = new player();
```